# How to reduce repeated code in foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel1.ToString()))
            {
                foreach (OtherFeatures of in FeaturesInfo)
                {
                    if (of != null)
                    {
                        of.PAN1 = View.Panel1;
                        of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
                        of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel2.ToString()))
            {
                foreach (OtherFeatures of in FeaturesInfo)
                {
                    if (of != null)
                    {
                        of.PAN2 = View.Panel2;
                        of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
                        of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel3.ToString()))
            {
                foreach (OtherFeatures of in FeaturesInfo)
                {
                    if (of != null)
                    {
                        of.PAN3 = View.Panel3;
                        of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
                        of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel4.ToString()))
            {
                foreach (OtherFeatures of in FeaturesInfo)
                {
                    if (of != null)
                    {
                        of.PAN4 = View.Panel4;
                        of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
                        of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel5.ToString()))
            {
                foreach (OtherFeatures of in FeaturesInfo)
                {
                    if (of != null)
                    {
                        of.PAN5 = View.Panel5;
                        of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
                        of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
.....
.....
```

I have a foreach loop like above and i'm repeating the same code inorder to pass each panel value.
I'm trying to reduce the repeated code like below( but not sure it is correct way )

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel1.ToString()))
{
   setpanelinfo(View.Panel1.ToString(),PAN1)
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel2.ToString()))
{
   setpanelinfo(View.Panel2.ToString(),PAN2)
}
....
....
....

public void setpanelinfo(string strpanelvalue, string PAN)
{
   foreach (OtherFeatures of in FeaturesInfo)
                {
                    if (of != null)
                    {
                        of.+ "PAN1" = strpanelvalue; // ERROR
                        of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
                        of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
}
```

Is there a better way to write this above foreach logic with minimal code?

Answer (score 2):

One approach to simplifying this is to use an `Action` callback for each specific case:

```
void HandlePanel(string panel, Action<OtherFeatures> action)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(panel))
    {
        foreach (var of in FeaturesInfo)
        {
            if (of != null)
            {
                action(of);
                of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
                of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

...

HandlePanel(View.Panel1.ToString(), of => of.PAN1 = View.Panel1);
HandlePanel(View.Panel2.ToString(), of => of.PAN2 = View.Panel2);
HandlePanel(View.Panel3.ToString(), of => of.PAN3 = View.Panel3);    
HandlePanel(View.Panel4.ToString(), of => of.PAN4 = View.Panel4);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Controls collection of the form object:
(typecast)Controls(of+"PAN1").SomeProperty = some value;

Comment: Any examples or can you change my code as per that systax.

Answer (score 0):

I just think foreach-ing the collection three times is a little wasteful. Maybe something like this might be a little more performant

```
foreach (var of in FeaturesInfo)
{
    if (of != null)
    {
        TestAndSet(View.Panel1.ToString(), text => of.PAN1 = text);
        TestAndSet(View.Panel2.ToString(), text => of.PAN2 = text);
        TestAndSet(View.Panel3.ToString(), text => of.PAN3 = text);
        of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
        of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;
        break;
    }
}
....
private void TestAndSet(String panel, Action<string> setAction)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(panel))
    {
       setAction(panel);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you can do only one foreach and move the test inside of the loop.

```
foreach (OtherFeatures of in FeaturesInfo)
{
    if (of != null)
    {
        of.NumOtherFeatures = null;
        of.OtherFeaturesDesc = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel1.ToString()))
            of.PAN1 = View.Panel1;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel2.ToString()))
            of.PAN2 = View.Panel2;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel3.ToString()))
            of.PAN3 = View.Panel3;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel4.ToString()))
            of.PAN4 = View.Panel4;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Panel5.ToString()))
            of.PAN5 = View.Panel5;

        break;
    }
}
```